# Uncountable subrings of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the only uncountable subring of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, there are some weird uncountable proper subrings. Not sure if we aren't allowed to use the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Let $X$ be a transcendence basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $Y$ be any proper uncountable subset of $X$. Then $\mathbb{Q}[Y]$ is uncountable and contained in $\mathbb{Q}(Y)\neq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The comment by @ArturoMagidin would remain correct even if one omitted the word "proper".  $\mathbb Q(X)\neq\mathbb R$; i.e., $\mathbb R$ is not a purely transcendental extension of $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 4):

As was pointed out in the comments, this is false. That can be shown even without the use of axiom of choice: you can explicitly construct uncountable algebraically independent subset $X$ of $\mathbb R$ (even ones of size continuum), see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23206/30186). For any such subset, $\mathbb Q(X)$ is an uncountable proper subfield of $\mathbb R$ - for any $x\in X$, either $x$ or $-x$ is positive, so either $\sqrt{x}$ or $\sqrt{-x}$ is in $\mathbb R$, but you can show it is not in $\mathbb Q(X)$.